# How to ask user to provide input in custom Console Command?

Tags: symfony

So I made command with two arguments:

```
class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('chat:server')
            ->setDescription('Start the Chat server')
            ->addArgument('host', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Provide a hostname')
            ->addArgument('port', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Provide a port number')
        ;
    }
```

but `server:chat` command not asking me to provide arguments.

How to ask user to provide input in custom Console Command?

Answer (score 9):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('chat:server')
        ->setDescription('Start the Chat server')
        ->addArgument('host', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Provide a hostname')
        ->addArgument('port', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Provide a port number')
    ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
    $question1 = new Question('Provide a hostname: ', 'localhost');
    $question2 = new Question('Provide a port number: ', '8080');

    $localhost = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question1);
    $port = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question2);
```

Comment: Hum, yes it can helpful to read the documentation before asking questions. ^^

Comment: sure, but more helpful is to google `How to ask user to provide input in custom Console Command?` and be moved here

Answer (score 6):

In addition to user6827096's answer: there's also the `interact()` method which can be used to pre-populate required options from interactive input using the question helper and will be called unless `--no-interaction` is passed to the command:

```
/**
 * Interacts with the user.
 *
 * This method is executed before the InputDefinition is validated.
 * This means that this is the only place where the command can
 * interactively ask for values of missing required arguments.
 *
 * @param InputInterface  $input  An InputInterface instance
 * @param OutputInterface $output An OutputInterface instance
 */
protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
}
```

A good example of its usage in combinatoin with the question helper can be found in Sensio's Generator Bundle which is shipped with Symfony: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateBundleCommand.php#L112